# rotate image 90 degrees around anchor point

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, cabasicanimation, quartz-core

I want to rotate my imageview 90 degrees around an anchor point. You can see what I want to achieve over here.[image]

I've got this piece of code.

```
CGFloat DegreesToRadians(CGFloat degrees)
{
    return degrees * M_PI / 180;
}

NSNumber* DegreesToNumber(CGFloat degrees)
{
    return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:
            DegreesToRadians(degrees)];
}
-(IBAction)rotate:(id)sender{
    CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation
                                           animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];

    [rotationAnimation setFromValue:DegreesToNumber(0)];
    [rotationAnimation setToValue:DegreesToNumber(90)];
    [rotationAnimation setDuration:3.0f];
    [rotationAnimation setRepeatCount:1];

    [[[self imgShare] layer] addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotate"];
}
```

There are a view problems. First when it rotates 90 degrees it immedialty flips back to its original state. Also I don't know how I can turn it arround an anchor point.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
self.imgShare.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `CABAsicAnimation` which just handles the animation part. To rotate your view after the rotation is your responsibility.
Therefore you should change the transform property of the view after the rotation.

```
self.imgShare.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

For your problem with the `anchorPoint`. Every `UIView` is backed by a `CALayer` and every `CALayer` has an `anchorPoint` property. Just change the views anchorpoint and you will be able to rotate the view around that point.

The `anchorPoint` defaults to 0.5,0.5. Change it between 0.0 and 1.0.